# How set default date value to today on Strapi

Tags: javascript, date, strapi, autofill

I was searching for a way to set the default date field value to today on Strapi, and I didn't found how to do this. After a while, I succeeded. Below is a step-by-step tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1 :

Enable default value in your date field of Content-Type Builder (the value is not relevant)

### Step 2 :

Create a JavaScript Module (don't forget to change "your-content-type-name" by the name of your content-type) :

`./src/api/your-content-type-name/content-types/your-content-type-name/auto-today.mjs`

```js
console.log(
  "\x1b[102m\x1b[97m\x1b[1m\x1b[3m%s\x1b[0m",
  "auto-today module is on!"
);

// Import "schedule" (for scheduled execution)
import schedule from "node-schedule";

// Import Node.js File System module
import fs from "fs";

// Scheduling of daily execution at midnight
let scheduleExec = schedule.scheduleJob("0 0 * * *", () => {
  // Get and store date, for most locales formats
  // (to be adapted for more uncommon locales formats)
  const date = new Date()
    .toLocaleString({
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "2-digit",
      year: "numeric",
    })
    .slice(0, 10)
    .replaceAll(/([./])/g, " ")
    .split(" ")
    .reverse()
    .join()
    .replaceAll(",", "-");

  // Read schema.json file
  fs.readFile(
    "./src/api/article/content-types/article/schema.json",
    function (err, data) {
      // Check for errors
      if (err) throw err;

      // Store schema.json a JavaScript object
      const schema = JSON.parse(data);

      // Remplace default date by today date
      schema.attributes.date.default = date;

      // Converting new schema.json JavaScript object to JSON object
      const newSchema = JSON.stringify(schema);

      // Remplace schema.json content by new content
      fs.writeFile(
        "./src/api/article/content-types/article/schema.json",
        newSchema,
        (err) => {
          // Error checking
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("schema.json updated");
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

### Step 3 :

Update the line `develop` in your package.json (as before don't forget to replace "your-content-type-name") :

`./backend/package.json`

```js
"auto-today": "node ./src/api/article/content-types/article/auto-today.mjs"
```

### How to use it ?

You just have to run `auto-today` at the same time as you run `develop`. Everyday at midnight, the script will be executed again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I first tought you want to set the default on creation or update but then saw you want to do it on a given time.

For anybody stumbling here wanting to know how to do this on creation/update, I would do it with lifecycle hooks. **The default value for the date field is necessary, but can be any date.** Create a lifecycles.js in your content-type:

```
// src/api/<your-type>/content-types/<your-type>/lifecycles.js
module.exports = {
    // or beforeUpdate(event) {
    beforeCreate(event) {
        const {data} = event.params;
        // dateField is your datefield
        data.dateField = new Date();
    }
}
```

That's all :)